# How to create a CNN cross filter for Tensorflow in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, filter, conv-neural-network

In general, the CNN model uses a square filter. I would like to use a cross filter or X filter. The function of creating a square filter in tensorflow is provided, but information on other filter-types is not available.

How can I make a cross filter and/or an X-filter?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the Javascript crossfilter library so I'm removing the tag.

Comment: that's okay:) thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use a Cross Filter, like the one whose shape is`3*4` rather than a Square Filter, whose shape is `3*3`.

If that is the case, that is allowed using the Function, `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D`.

In the argument, `kernel_size`, you need to provide `(3,4)` instead of `just 3` or `(3,3)`.